# DataType string for attr 'TI' not in list of allowed values: uint8, int32, int64

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have been using a CNN for text classification and have used tensorflow's contrib learn.

However, when I try to execute the following code:

```
classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model)

classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, steps=10000) 
y_predicted = [ p['class'] for p in classifier.predict(x_test, as_iterable=True)] 

score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted) 

print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(score))
```

I am running in the following error:

> ERROR:DataType string for attr 'TI' not in list of allowed values:
>   uint8, int32, int64 on line 'classifier.fit'

Comment: I have formatted your code a bit, please check that the content is still correct. And, wild guessing: could it be that `y_train` should represent classes as integers, but actually contains floats?

Comment: y_train contains 0 and 1.

Comment: And x_train contains array of numbers

Comment: Hm, I'm not familiar with contrib.learn. But probably you should still include the definitions of `x_train` and `y_train`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your inputs `y_train` to the given type. 
`print(type(y_train))` most likely is a float instead of an integer.

Comment: They are all ints (1's and 0's)